# Copy range value of cells by finding from another cell

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I attempt to duplicate a column J (J2:J7) by formula to show in the column L (L2:L7) as shown in the figure. However, cell L8 is a like a cell that I want to call that column. For example, if I input 30 in cell L8, L2:L7 will show 1,2,3,5,4,6 respectively.

Could you suggest a good solution for me either VBA or normal formular? Thank You in Advance

Comment: Try: `=XLOOKUP(L8,G8:K8,G2:K7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Sub FindAndCopy()
    
    Dim found As Range, i As Long, searchValue
    
    searchValue = Range("L8").Value
    
    Set found = Range("A8:K8").Find(searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        For i = 2 To 7
            Cells(i, "L") = Cells(i, found.Column)
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "Search value not found in range A8:K8"
    End If
End Sub
```

or in worksheet change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim found As Range, i As Long, searchValue

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L8")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        searchValue = Target.Value

        Set found = Range("A8:K8").Find(searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not found Is Nothing Then
          
          For i = 2 To 7
             Cells(i, "L") = Cells(i, found.Column)
          Next i
        Else
          MsgBox "Search value not found in range A8:K8"
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```